# Cannot rewrite Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal

Tags: model, sales, magento-community, quote

For one of my module I’m trying to rewrite the class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal.
I used to rewrite models, no problem with that. I understand that the abstract classes cannot be rewritten.
But this one, I’m stuck ...

My aim is to rewrite protected function _initItem($address, $item), I have failed, and tryed to rewrite every function (with parent:: replacement by grandparent class). No more luck for me.

Here is my config :

```
<!-- in app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/etc/config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
    <models>
        <sales_quote>
            <rewrite>
                <address_total_subtotal>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal</address_total_subtotal>
            </rewrite>
        </sales_quote>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

And my class :

```
# in app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Model/Sales/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal
{
protected function _initItem($address, $item)
{
    Mage::log("rewrite");
}
}
```

Can anyone help me with that ? Seems to be the same problem as an abstract class so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<sales_quote>
        <rewrite>
            <address_total_subtotal>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal</address_total_subtotal>
        </rewrite>
    </sales_quote>
```

Should be

```
<sales>
        <rewrite>
            <quote_address_total_subtotal>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal</quote_address_total_subtotal>
        </rewrite>
    </sales>
```

Comment: This is it ! I found a tutorial, for some models like Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item_Api_V2 you have to put cataloginventory_stock before the rewrite tag. Can you explain me that point please ? Thank you very much by the way !

Comment: @guillaume_shm if you post a link I can try to explain

Comment: thanks for your contribution, I found that it was the aliases defined in the core config.xml associated to the class I want to rewrite. So far, I'm good and I have totally understood how it work. Thank you very much again !

Answer (score 0):

Here is some notes given on image, try to understand how to create model names and rewrite in config.xml:
[image: Model rewrite]

Comment: Oh clever explanation, thank you very much mageUz !